# How to set array of pointers to arrays correctly in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say I have defined these 3 arrays:

```
int[][3] arr0 = { 
    {1,2,3}, 
    {4,5,6} 
};

int[][3] arr1 = { 
    {10,20,30}, 
    {40,50,60}, 
    {70,80,90} 
};
int[][3] arr2 = { 
    {100,200,300}, 
    {400,500,600}, 
    {700,800,900}, 
    {1000,1100,1200}
};
```

Now I want to make an array of pointers leading to these arrays, something like:

```
// pseudo code example
arrays[] = {
    arr0, 
    arr1, 
    arr2
};
```

Because I then want to get the k-th value from the j-th sub-array of variable "arrayN" this way:

```
// pseudo code example
int value = arrays[N][j][k];
```

For example: N is 2, j is 1 and k is 0, the target array is arr2, so the value should be 400.

How can I write this code correctly in C? I tried many ways and none worked.

Comment: Please show us what did not work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers to array won't work as you want.

To archive what you want, I think using array of pointer to `int[3]` is good.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N = 2, j = 1, k = 0;
    int arr0[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
    int arr1[][3] = { {10,20,30}, {40,50,60}, {70,80,90} };
    int arr2[][3] = { {100,200,300}, {400,500,600}, {700,800,900}, {1000,1100,1200} };

    int (*arrays[])[3]={arr0,arr1,arr2};
    int value = arrays[N][j][k];

    printf("%d\n",value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Thanks, this works! :-) Edit: I thought I tried this too but I propably didn't use the square brackets next to arrays after defining the *arrays...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
int (*arr[])[3] = {arr0, arr1, arr2};
for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != i+2 ; j++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", arr[i][j][0], arr[i][j][1], arr[i][j][2]);
    }
}
```

which prints

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
100 200 300
400 500 600
700 800 900
1000 1100 1200
```

The key to the solution is this declaration:

```
int (*arr[])[3]
```

It means "declare `arr` to be an array of pointers to arrays of three integers".

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/chleDR)

Answer (score 1):

There's some problems with this approach. The empty dimension `[]` means "allocate an array as large as there are items in the initializer list". And the only thing the compiler cares about in the initializer list is the number of `{}` pairs, because each such brace pair will be an array initializer.

Since you specified the inner most dimension to `[3]`, it will try to create as many arrays of length `[3]` as there are brace pairs. In the first example there are 2 brace pairs, so 2 arrays will be needed. The type of `arr0` will therefore be `int [2][3]`.

Same applies to the other arrays, which will get different types: `int [3][3]` and `int [4][3]` respectively.

So you have 3 different types. You cannot make an array of these 3 different types no more than you can make an array out of lets say 1 `char`, 1 `int` and 1 `float`.

---

There are a couple of solutions. Either you don't care about memory allocated nor variable array lengths. Then you can set both dimensions to fixed size. With all arrays of type `int [4][3]` you can then declare an array of such arrays.

Or alternatively you can make an array of pointers, each pointing at the first item in each array:

`int* arr_list = {arr0, arr1, arr2};`

With either of these solutions, you'll be able to access the items as `[x][y][z]`.